Find Value in Rows that are in multiple columns
I have a table called CPW Detections and it looks something like this in the columns
|Site|Set Date|Removal Date|Point Location|Species 1|Detection 1|Species 2|Detection 2| and so on..
What i would like to do is find all the rows (including site, removal date, point location) that have (for example) the field "Numbat" and its # of Detections (Detections column). Now the Numbat could be in any of the Species 1 through to Species 21 Columns. How can i do this and how can i do it so that i can find any specific species?

Normalize. Detection and Species should be in a related table where each detection/species is a record - linking would possibly be on PointLocationID. Working with current structure will require either: 1) UNION query to rearrange detection/species fields to normalized structure that can be filtered; or 2) VBA custom function.

Can try putting "Numbat" under each Species field on a separate row so the SQL builds criteria with OR operator. Make it dynamic by using an input prompt instead [enter search text here] or refence a control on form Forms!FormName!textboxname. Whichever, it will get ugly.

As @June7 pointed out, the data-model is not right here: detections had to be in its own table.
Albeit, if you have to query this, you need to use 21 queries, whose results unioned into one set/query:
select Site, SetDate, RemovalDate, PointLocation, Detections1
from CPWDetections
where Species1='Numbat'
union all
select Site, SetDate, RemovalDate, PointLocation, Detections2
from CPWDetections
where Species2='Numbat'
...
...
union all
select Site, SetDate, RemovalDate, PointLocation, Detections21
from CPWDetections
where Species21='Numbat'

Fill in the part with ...!
